# emit a json array from servlet

Tags: json, servlets

I have been able to send out a json object from a servlet using import org.json.JSONObject;
Please see my code below

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                response.setContentType("application/json");
                response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "nocache");
                response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

                // put a "person" 
                JSONObject person = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    person.put("age", "24");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    person.put("gender", "M");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    person.put("ID", "10082");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    json.put("person", person);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // finally output the json string       
                out.print(json.toString());
}
```

This gives me a json response like :

```
{"person":{"age":"24","gender":"M","ID":"10082"}}
```

However, I would like to get an array of 3 json objects as folllows. How can I get that?

```
[
    {
        "age": "21",
        "gender": "M",
        "ID": "10092"
    },
    {
        "age": "25",
        "gender": "M",
        "ID": "10091"
    },
    {
        "age": "24",
        "gender": "M",
        "ID": "10095"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to create different JSON object for each user and then put all those in JSON Array . And Finally add the array to main JSON object. You can get the idea from the following code(I am assuming that your data is in some ArrayList eg All_Users . ):

```
JSONObject main_JSON_Object =new JSONObject();
JSONArray main_JSON_Array=new JSONArray();

    for(int i= 0;i<All_Users.size();i++)
                 {
                     JSONObject user_Object=new JSONObject();

                                try
                                {

                                user_Object.put("person", All_Users.get(i));
                                }
                                catch(NullPointerException ex)
                                {

                                }

                                 main_JSON_Array.put(user_Object);
                       }

                 main_JSON_Object.put("userarray", main_JSON_Array);
```

Comment: ok I'm trying these out now. I'm not comfortable with Lists etc, so will have to learn these first. Will get back to you after I have learnt and tried out.

Comment: It is not necessary to have the data in lists only . From where you are getting the above values that you have used to explain the type of JSON Object you want to create ?

Answer (score 0):

**Using JSONArray and JSONObject**

1. create a JSON Object

`JSONObject objJSON =new JSONObject();`

2. create a JSON array

`JSONArray arrJSON =new JSONArray();`

3. Loop Over collection that contains data, suppose a RESULSET from DB

```
    while(resultset.next()){

                // put a "person" 
                JSONObject person = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    person.put("age", "24");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    person.put("gender", "M");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    person.put("ID", "10082");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    arrJSON .add(person);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

     }

    objJSON.put("person",arrJSON  );
```

If you get any exception while using `objJSON.put("person",arrJSON  );` try this `objJSON.put("person",(Object)arrJSON );`.

You will get a structure like this, the way you want.

```
{"person" : [{"age":"24","gender":"M","ID":"10082"},{"age":"25","gender":"F","ID":"10083"},{"age":"26","gender":"O","ID":"10084"}]
```

**Using Map and List**

```
LinkedList listOfPerson = new LinkedList();

while(resultset.next()){

            // put a "person" 
            Map person = new HashMap();
            try {
                person.put("age", "24");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                person.put("gender", "M");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                person.put("ID", "10082");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                listOfPerson.add(person);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

 }

objJSON.put("person",listOfPerson);
```

Comment: Thank you I was able to get my json array as follows : [{"name":"abc","age":"80","gender":"male"},{"name":"hello","age":"45","gender":"female"}]
I have a question though, shouldn't the array have the name at the beginning, like the following. How do I add that? "nameofarray" = [{"name":"abc","age":"80","gender":"male"},{"name":"hello","age":"45","gender":"female"}]
I'm sorry for the late reply, I was getting errors in spite of adding java-json.jar but searching a bit got to know that I have to add the jar in Deployment Assembly.

Comment: @IAMTubby Did this json array `[{"name":"abc","age":"80","gender":"male"},{"name":"hello","age":"45","gender":"‌​female"}]` came after you accessed it by it's object name i.e "person". For example if you do this `objJSON .get("person")` then you will receive only `[{"name":"abc","age":"80","gender":"male"},{"name":"hello","age":"45","gender":"‌​female"}]`. Because you have used key `person`,it will not appear as part of JsonArray, so what you get is it's value. To get whole structure print JSONObject without extracting the value.

Comment: @IAMTubby You can try this `JSONObject objJSONContainer =new JSONObject(); objJSONContainer.put("PersonList",objJSON);` , add this line after `objJSON.put("person",arrJSON  );`. Then use `PersonList` as key and you will get your desired structure , as it's value.